# pagina en blanco al loguearme

Tags: laravel-5, apache, xampp

Llevo dias con un problema que francamente no se por que me pasa.

El tema es que tengo un proyecto en localhost, que funcionaba a la perfeccion, y funcionaba todo, hasta que intente optimizarla (que no estoy seguro que sea por eso), usando la cache(postsController)....pero incluso usando la cache, seguia funcionando perfectamente, de hecho estuve toda una tarde trabajando sin ningun problema, pero al dia siguiente, despues de intentar loguearme (con el usuario correcto) al darle al login, en vez de salirme el panel de administracion, me llevaba a una pagina en blanco.

He intentado todo
Composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
incluso he borrado manualmente todos los archivos de cada una de las carpetas de "storage".
Uso windows 7 y la carpeta storage tiene permisos.

También he quitado las rutas en las que tiene que cargar previamente el middleware de login, y la carga perfectamente

routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => 'auth'],
function() {

    Route::get('dashboard', 'admin\adminController@getDashboard');
    Route::resource('posts', 'postController');
    Route::get('notificaciones', 'postController@vistaNotificaciones');
});    

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function() {
    Route::get('iniciar', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');

});


Route::post('iniciar', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('registro', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegistro');
Route::post('registro', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegistro');
```

AuthController

```
 protected $redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';

     protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/iniciar';


    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
      $this->auth = $auth;

    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        $reglas =  [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:1|confirmed',
                  ];
        $mensajes =    [
            'required' => 'El campo :attribute es requerido',
            'email' => 'El campo :atribute tiene que tener formato de email',
                    ];

        return  Validator::make($data, $reglas, $mensajes);
    }
     protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
              'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    public function comprobarValidacion(\Request $request)
    {
         $validador =  $this->validator($request::all());
           $errors = $validador->errors()->all();
           return $validador;
    }

    public function getRegistro()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }
   public function postRegistro(\Request $request)
    {
            $validador =  $this->validator($request::all());

           $errors = $validador->errors()->all();

           if(count($errors)>0):

             return Redirect()->back()->withErrors($validador);

            endif;


        $this->create($request::all());

          \Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/sistema.log');
         \Log::info('El usuario '.$request::get('name').' con correo '.$request::get('email').' ha sido creado a las '.date('d-m-Y H:m'));
        \Session::flash('creado','El usuario '.$request::get('name').' ha sido creado exitosamente');
        return Redirect()->back();

    }

     protected function validatorLogin(array $data)
    {

        $reglas =  [
           'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
                  ];
        $mensajes =    [
            'required' => 'El campo :attribute es requerido',
            'email' => 'El campo :atribute tiene que tener formato de email',
                    ];

        return  Validator::make($data, $reglas, $mensajes);
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {

        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)

    {
              $validador =  $this->validatorLogin($request::all());
              $errors = $validador->errors()->all();

             if($validador->fails()):
                 return Redirect()->back()->withErrors($validador);
             endif;

            $datos = array('email' => $request::get('email'),

                             'password' => $request::get('password')
                                    );

     if (\Auth::attempt($datos)) :

                 \Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/sistema.log');
                    \Log::info('El usuario '.\Auth::user()->name.' con correo '.\Auth::user()->email.' se ha loqueado a las '.date('d-m-Y H:m'));
                      return Redirect()->to($this->redirectTo); 

            endif;



    }
```

PostController

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {


     //  $listapost = \App\modelos//\post::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->paginate(20);

      $pagina = $request->page;


  //    CACHEANDO LA PAGINACION
         $listapost = \Cache::remember('listapost_'.$pagina,100,function(){
               return \App\modelos\post::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->paginate(20);
       });
        return View('backend.posts.listaposts',compact('listapost'));

    }
```

Del post controller pongo solamente el metodo index por que es el que tendria que cargar despues del login, pero no lo carga nunca, (salvo que quite la ruta del middleware y acceda directamente entonces si lo carga bien).

Cuando introduzco el login correctamente me tendria que redireccionar a admin/dashboard, y sin embargo se me queda en iniciar.
He probado a modificar con un dd el metodo post login(la ruta post de iniciar) para ver si carga el metodo y lo carga perfectamente.

Tambien he vaciado completamente la cache del navegador (firefox), y he probado tambien en otro navegador(chrome) y mismo resultado, despues de loguear pagina en blanco quedandose en la ruta de iniciar.

Tambien añadir que he reiniciado el sistema varias veces sin ningun cambio.
Pese a ser repetitivo me gustaria recalcar que todo esto me ha estado funcionando perfectamente durante dias, solo desde hace dos me ha pasado esto

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: te recomiendo que le des un vistazo al Log del apache, para que veas que error tienes, lo mas probable es que sea un error 500, necesitas revisar el error en el apache, con eso podras saber como resolver tu problema. saludos.

Comment: Lo he mirado y no, me sale este error """[Wed Nov 16 13:10:45.311009 2016] [core:error] [pid 3196:tid 1604] (OS 5)?????????????  : [client ::1:60965] AH00127: Cannot map GET /ficheros/ HTTP/1.1 to file
[Wed Nov 16 13:10:45.311009 2016] [core:error] [pid 3196:tid 1604] (OS 5)?????????????  : [client ::1:60965] AH00127: Cannot map GET /ficheros/ HTTP/1.1 to file""", he reinstalado de nuevo xampp en otra carpeta y nada, sigue dandome error, ayer parecia que se habia arreglado y hoy de nuevo la pagina en blanco.

Comment: me he instalado el xampp 5.6.24